# ac fan check 2007 wolfburg edition

Tags: vw, ac, fan

does the engine have to be running or on to check if ac fan works i was told my fan don't work I want to check my fan. Ac on engine running my fan spins

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I am happy to be on this exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fan can come on when the AC is on and the compressor is running, or when the car gets up to temperature and needs to cool the radiator and cooling system. *Something* needs to be happening to see if the fan is working properly. You could possibly pull the fan relay and jump it directly, causing the fan to energize. Really, if you can see the fan on with the AC running, I'd think there's no issue there.

Comment: PAULSTER2 your comment was spot on my fan works perfectly

Comment: @michaelwilson - If this answers your question, please select the check mark below the voting arrows on the left side of my answer.